# What could be a better solution to calling a function recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-management

This is a simple function which will take value from user and if value is invalid then the function will call itself recursively until a valid input is provided.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void getnum(){
    int num;
    string strnum;
    getline(cin, strnum);
    try{
        num = stoi(strnum); 
    }
    catch(invalid_argument &ia){
        cout<<"Invalid argument\n";
        getnum();
    }

    cout<<"\n"<<num;
}

int main(){
    getnum();
    return 0;
}
/*output(input: abc,abc,abc,4):
4
2494464
2494464
4201200
*/
```

Using the recursive approach the program is creating a new instance of the function every time an invalid argument is passed. After receiving a valid argument, function is printing multiple values(garbage values) of `num` due to multiple instances created.

The problem is that I want only the last value(correct one) to be printed. So I tried setting a 'flag' to control the execution of `cout<<"\n"<<num`.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void getnum(){
    int flag = 0;
    int num;
    string strnum;
    getline(cin, strnum);
    try{
        flag = 1;
        num = stoi(strnum); 
    }
    catch(invalid_argument &ia){
        flag = 0;
        cout<<"Invalid argument\n";
        getnum();
    }
    if(flag)
    cout<<"\n"<<num;
}

int main(){
    getnum();
    return 0;
}
/*output(input:abc,abc,abc,4)
4 */
```

It solves my problem but still multiple instances are being created which I think is wastage of memory.

Is there any better way to do this without using a lot of memory(recursion)?

Comment: endless loop around the `try catch`, move the `cout` and add `return;` into the `try`.

Comment: did you learn about loops?

Comment: @user253751 yes I know loops but had no idea on implementing here. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: That function does too many things. It collects input and it displays what it got. Separate those two. The function should get the input and return the result. Its caller should do whatever is needed with the result, in this case, display it.

Comment: @pete the function i provided above is just a sample for explaining the problem. Actual function was different and it was suitable to print the result instead of returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get multiple outputs because you print outside "the happy path" - move printing inside the try block.
It's even clearer to put the entire "happy path" inside the try:

```
void getnum(){
    try {
        string strnum;
        getline(cin, strnum);
        int num = stoi(strnum); 
        cout<<"\n"<<num;
    }
    catch(invalid_argument &ia){
        cout<<"Invalid argument\n";
        getnum();
    }
}
```

The idiomatic solution is to loop rather than recurse:

```
void getnum(){
    while (true)
    {
        try {
            string strnum;
            getline(cin, strnum);
            int num = stoi(strnum); 
            cout << "\n" << num;
            return;
        }
        catch (invalid_argument &){
            cout<<"Invalid argument\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Throwing `cout` is now considered as invalid argument though.